# Modify generic Chinese LED driver circuit

Tags: led, switches, integrated-circuit, driver

I have a lot of LED flashlights and lanterns from China that use a simple IC as their driver to get these different light modes. For instance I have this small keyfob lamp that lights in the following modes when the momentary tactile button is pressed - (High mode -> Low mode -> Blinking Mode -> Off), and yes I have to cycle through all modes to turn it off. Additionally long pressing the button will make it go into an SOS flasher mode.

I opened up the lamp and took a close look and found there only a total of 4 components, the LED, a momentary switch, a 3R0 SMD resistor and finally a SOT23-6 type IC with “*2819*” written on it. I googled for that IC and found it’s FM2819 by “*Shenzhen Fuman Elec*” and found its [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1145491/FUMAN/FM2819/+01455A4XETMwPdISY.YH+/datasheet.pdf) too. The circuit used in the lamp is exactly the same as the one shown in the datasheet.

What I want to know is that is there any way of modifying the circuit/wiring to get rid of all these light modes? since all I want is just plain ‘ON’ and ‘OFF’.

- *SW in the circuit is for switch*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your S1 is almost certainly not an closing switch,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9MQXw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but a momentary pushbutton,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f96ftd.png)</sup>

considering it's used to cycle through modes.

This sounds very much like

> Throw away existing circuit, replace S1 by toggling button, be done.

Alternatively, you could also

> Throw away existing circuit, replace with circuit that toggles output based on push button.

But that'll require a couple more components (two transistors for toggling, plus a bit of capacitance for  de-ringing  the pushbutton) or a small microcontroller (e.g. an Attiny8).

Modification of the existing circuit is not really an option – it's almost certain that the IC is single-purpose; I can't read the datasheet in Chinese, but seeing that it's only 2 pages in length, it's certainly not a programmable controller.

Comment: The circuit board is really small, so is the enclosure. If I have to use a toggle/latching switch then it must the same size of that momentary button, which is 5mm*5mm. I don’t think latching switches come in that size.

Comment: You are right about the button diagram. Will 2 additional transistors and a capacitor replace this circuit?

Comment: ... together with at least two resistors, yes, you can make a latch from two transistors. probably larger than an Attiny8.

Comment: The IC provides more than just the light mode, from an translation it does current limiting, pwm, and other functions, based on R. Replacing it with a single switch would likely poof the led.

Comment: @Passerby won’t the smd resistor do the trick for current limiting?

Comment: @MarcusMüller let’s say I go for an Attiny10. I still need a transistor to drive the leds right? Since the led require like 100ma, since it’s more than what an i/o pin can handle?

Comment: @Kokachi a simple smd resistor is typically not used for 1W or higher leds. One being they typically do not have the wattage rating to support the current involved. It will depend on voltage. As for ATTiny, yes, 100 mA is more than a single pin can support. A transistor or mosfet is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for lanterns, I can advice module, that I use by my self. With capacitor sensor.

Simple and cheap ttp223, you can set up  output "polarity", and trigger action (latching) by fuses. just add some MOSFET and few resistors. https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/32957041799.html

And "powerful" OE-TP module, based on SGL8022W IC. It can be configurated as dimmer regulator, or "sharp" on\off switch.
https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/32974849050.html

P.S. Capacity sensor is great decision, but it can indecently triggered by water or pets.
P.P.S. Also you can look on E-cigarette flow sensor...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I search same information, and find. Just on\off IC.
<del>YUSIJIE-LSM01</del> YUSIJIE-LM01

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/YUSIJIE-LM01-LED-control-chip-Trigger_62490420642.html
(video present)

And very possible it used in this China modules...
https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005002730537353.html

With hall-sensor CC6201ST
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811061532_Cross-chip-CC6201ST_C285995.pdf

Comment: That chip is not "just on/off", it is On-Flash-Off.

Comment: Oh! my mistake.... on\off model is YUSIJIE-LM01 https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/YUSIJIE-LM01-LED-control-chip-Trigger_62490420642.html?spm=a2700.shop_plgr.41413.16.8cdf4fe1MZd6aR

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/348094)